# Does an upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 will effect the version of PHP/other packages installed?

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade, php

My work laptop is running Ubuntu 12.10 (32-bit). Due to the need to be able to test our code in the same versions of PHP, Memcache, and a few other modules; I need to keep the PHP version right where they are at (for example PHP 5.3.x). However I would like to upgrade to my current OS version to Ubuntu 13.04.

Can I upgrade without worrying that Ubuntu will also upgrade the PHP package and other related packages? Or will it just do that whether I like it or not?

Thanks!

Edit:
After running "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -V" I get the following results:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   libmemcached6 (0.44-1.1build1)
   php5-intl (5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4)
   php5-memcached (2.0.1-6)
   php5-xsl (5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libjs-underscore (1.3.3-1ubuntu1)
   libmemcached10 (1.0.8-1)
   libmemcachedutil2 (1.0.8-1)
   linux-headers-3.5.0-40 (3.5.0-40.62)
   linux-headers-3.5.0-40-generic (3.5.0-40.62)
   linux-image-3.5.0-40-generic (3.5.0-40.62)
   linux-image-extra-3.5.0-40-generic (3.5.0-40.62)
The following packages have been kept back:
   php-apc (3.1.7-1 => 3.1.13-1)
The following packages will be upgraded:
   libmemcached-tools (0.44-1.1build1 => 1.0.8-1)
   linux-headers-generic (3.5.0.31.47 => 3.5.0.40.56)
   linux-image-generic (3.5.0.31.47 => 3.5.0.40.56)
   mercurial (2.6.1-1ppa1~quantal1 => 2.7-0ppa1~quantal1)
   mercurial-common (2.6.1-1ppa1~quantal1 => 2.7-0ppa1~quantal1)
   tortoisehg (2.8-0ppa1~quantal1 => 2.9-0ppa1~quantal1)
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
   libapache2-mod-php5 (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-cli (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-common (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-curl (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-gd (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-mysql (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-sqlite (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
   php5-sybase (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
```

So it looks like I would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. PHP is not a dependency of Ubuntu 13.04.

FYI, when you do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` via the command line, it will list all packages that are slated for upgrade. You can double check for PHP's existence.

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't tell the version unless you use the `-v` switch.

Comment: And this is what I ended up using to make my final decision. So WINNER!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found something really interesting while I was searching some more points for your question. This will help you understand more about an **Upgrading process**. You may read it **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34605/how-does-the-ubuntu-upgrade-process-work/209927#209927)**. In addition to that, I assume below will help you to understand too;

As I know, **Ubuntu** by default doesn't have Apache, PHP, MySQL running. You will have to install afterwards. And an OS upgrade will not effect your `/home/` files but all system settings `/etc/` with the set of default (automatically) installed packages. Since **LAMP** isn't a default package, I don't think it will make any changes unless if there's any needs. Because the updater looks for a newer version of manually installed packages.

To further investigate, you can use `sudo apt-mark showmanual package-name` or just `sudo apt-mark showmanual` to check for the manual and `sudo apt-mark showauto` to view automatically installed packages.

Sources which helped me to collect info;

- **[Ubuntu Upgrade Notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes)**
- **[Upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RaringUpgrades)**

Hope these helps!

Comment: Looks like I got some more reading today. Thanks for the info!